# Pagination on SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was trying to fetch data from SQL SERVER 2008 using pagination.

my procedure was :

```
CREATE PROC Paginate
@PageSize int, @PageNumber int 
AS 
Declare @RowStart int 
Declare @RowEnd int 
if @PageNumber > 0 
Begin 
SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber -1 
SET @RowStart = @PageSize * @PageNumber + 1; 
SET @RowEnd = @RowStart + @PageSize - 1 ; 
With claim_user_info_paginate AS 
 ( SELECT userNbr, userName, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by userNbr) as UserNumber 
   FROM claim_user_info ) 
select * 
from claim_user_info_paginate 
Where UserNumber >= @RowStart and UserNumber <= @RowEnd
END
```

I need to fetch record continuously but the above procedure returns only first 10. In this case what should i do to get all the records continuously in my table using java.

my java code:

```
String sql="exec Paginate 10,1";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

I have tried to loop the query but i got the same result continuously. Can some one say where i have too do correction.

Comment: In the loop, did you change the sql string? so from *String sql="exec Paginate 10,1";* to *String sql="exec Paginate 10,2";* or at least use a counter to increment the page number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this tabe value function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPagedData] 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @pagesize int, 
    @pageindex int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

     SELECT TOP (@pagesize) * ,Row_number() Over(order by a.ID) as count FROM 
     (
          SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS num              
          FROM dbo.Employees where IsActive=1
     ) AS a
     WHERE num > @pageindex*@pagesize
)
```

Use like this 
select * from dbo.GetPagedData(pagesize,pageindex)
i.e select * from dbo.GetPagedData(20,0)
**Note: page index starts from 0.**

In Java loop over this function by incrementing pageindex each time.

Answer (score 1):

I have created my store procedures which do pagination , compare it with yours and then try :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_get_persons] (@pageNo   INT, 
                                        @pageSize INT) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT id, 
             name, 
             [desc], 
             [address], 
             phone, 
             email 
      FROM   (SELECT id, 
                     name, 
                     [desc], 
                     [address], 
                     phone, 
                     email, 
                     Row_number() 
                       OVER ( 
                         ORDER BY id ) AS RowNum 
              FROM   persons.dbo.person) person 
      WHERE  person.rownum BETWEEN ( ( @pageNo - 1 ) * @pageSize + 1 ) AND ( 
                                   @pageNo * @pageSize ) 
  END
```